# Dice Game Conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, dice

My function match() is not working...I thought I can store the return value of playerGameOne and playerGameTwo so I can compare the values of playerOne and playerTwo, and then compare. This doesn't seem to be the logic, since my function will just generate random display messages and not following the conditions I set upon in the match function. But the console log is showing different values from what I rolled. Please help:

```js
        const max = 8
        const para = document.querySelector('p')
        const buttonOne = document.querySelector('button.first')
        const buttonTwo = document.querySelector('button.second')
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
        
        let playerOne
        let playerTwo
        let playerPoints = 0
        let x
        let y
        function playerGameOne(){
           let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max));
            playerOne = (random + 1)
            return playerOne
        }
        
        function playerGameTwo(){
           let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max));
            playerTwo = (random + 1)
            return playerTwo
        }
        
        function displayMessageOne(){
            const para = document.createElement('p')
            para.innerText = `Your rolled a ${playerOne} on the dice.`
            document.body.append(para)
        }
        function displayMessageTwo(){
            const para = document.createElement('p')
            para.innerText = `Your rolled a ${playerTwo} on the dice.`
            document.body.append(para)
        }
        function displaySuccessMatchMessage(){
            // if(playerPoints === 5){
            //     para.innerText = "Congratulations! You got 5 points. Play again."
            //     return document.body.append(para)
            // }
            const para = document.createElement('p');
            para.innerText = `You gained a point! You have ${playerPoints}.`
            document.body.append(para)
        }
        function displayFailedMatchMessage(){
            const para = document.createElement('p');
            para.innerText = "Try again."
            document.body.append(para)
        }
       
        function diceOne(){
            playerGameOne();
            displayMessageOne()
        }
        function diceTwo(){
            playerGameTwo();
            displayMessageTwo();
        };
        
       function match(){
            
            playerGameOne();
            playerGameTwo();
            x = playerGameOne(); 
            y = playerGameTwo();
            console.log(x+y) //getting different log values 
            if((x+y) > 8){
                playerPoints+=1;
                displaySuccessMatchMessage();
            }else{
                playerPoints+=0;
                displayFailedMatchMessage()
            } 
            if(playerPoints === 5){
                displaySuccessMatchMessage()
            }
            
        }
    

        buttonOne.addEventListener('click', diceOne)
        buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', diceTwo)
        buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', match)
```

```css
            h1, div, p{
                text-align: center;
            }
            img{
                width: 200px;
            }
```

```html
        <h1>
            Click on me: Goal is to get to 5 points.
        </h1>
        <div>
        <button class="first">
            <img class = "firstImage" src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/dice-B5mdRR0-600.jpg"> 
        </button>
        <button class="second">
           <img class = "secondImage" src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/dice-B5mdRR0-600.jpg"> 
        </button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting x and y in your diceOne and diceTwo functions.

```js
const max = 8
        const para = document.querySelector('p')
        const buttonOne = document.querySelector('button.first')
        const buttonTwo = document.querySelector('button.second')
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
        
        let playerOne
        let playerTwo
        let playerPoints = 0
        let x = 0
        let y = 0
        function playerGameOne(){
           let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max));
            playerOne = (random + 1)
            return playerOne
        }
        
        function playerGameTwo(){
           let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max));
            playerTwo = (random + 1)
            return playerTwo
        }
        
        function displayMessageOne(){
            const para = document.createElement('p')
            para.innerText = `Your rolled a ${playerOne} on the dice.`
            document.body.append(para)
        }
        function displayMessageTwo(){
            const para = document.createElement('p')
            para.innerText = `Your rolled a ${playerTwo} on the dice.`
            document.body.append(para)
        }
        function displaySuccessMatchMessage(){
            // if(playerPoints === 5){
            //     para.innerText = "Congratulations! You got 5 points. Play again."
            //     return document.body.append(para)
            // }
            const para = document.createElement('p');
            para.innerText = `You gained a point! You have ${playerPoints}.`
            document.body.append(para)
        }
        function displayFailedMatchMessage(){
            const para = document.createElement('p');
            para.innerText = "Try again."
            document.body.append(para)
        }
       
        function diceOne(){
            x = playerGameOne(); //update x
            displayMessageOne()
        }
        function diceTwo(){
            y = playerGameTwo(); //update y
            displayMessageTwo();
        };
        
       function match(){
            
            //use functions diceOne and diceTwo to set x and y
            //playerGameOne();
            //playerGameTwo();
            //x = playerGameOne();
            //y = playerGameTwo();
            console.log(x+y) //getting different log values 
            if((x+y) > 8){
                playerPoints+=1;
                displaySuccessMatchMessage();
            }else{
                playerPoints+=0;
                displayFailedMatchMessage()
            } 
            if(playerPoints === 5){
                displaySuccessMatchMessage()
            }
            
        }
    
        //diceOne and diceTwo now set x and y
        buttonOne.addEventListener('click', diceOne) 
        buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', diceTwo)
        buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', match)
```

```css
h1, div, p{
                text-align: center;
            }
            img{
                width: 200px;
            }
```

```html
<h1>
            Click on me: Goal is to get to 5 points.
        </h1>
        <div>
        <button class="first">
            <img class = "firstImage" src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/dice-B5mdRR0-600.jpg"> 
        </button>
        <button class="second">
           <img class = "secondImage" src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/dice-B5mdRR0-600.jpg"> 
        </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dillon. So I am lost as to what to set x and y.. I know I want the value of playerOne and playerTwo, respectively. And I was taught to just set a variable to my function to get and store the return value...

Comment: You were setting x and y correctly previously, but you recalculated them a couple times which is why you were receiving unexpected output. In the code snippet above you can see that I am still setting x and y to the values that playerGameOne and playerGameTwo return, however, I am only setting them once when the click event listeners call diceOne and diceTwo.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I understand it now! I keep thinking that in the match function that it would not be able to grab the x and y values so I put x = playerOne and y = playerTwo inside the match function. It didn't occur to me that even though it would be updated in another function, since it is a global variable the updated variable can still be accessed by other functions.

Comment: No problem, and exactly x and y are global variables so you need to be careful about which functions are updating them. Please mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question, thanks!